# How do I get my body to the bottom of my page OR further if necessary?

Tags: html, css, document-body

```css
html, body {cursor:url(files/cursor.cur),progress;min-height:100%;}
html{background-color:#6666FF;;background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;background-size:cover;}
body{width:80%;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}
p{margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;text-align: center;}
iframe{overflow:hidden;height:80%;width:100%;}
img{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:calibri;border-style:outset;border-color:#FFFF00;border-width:5px;}
td{font-size:16px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFF00;background-color:#FFFFFF}
th{font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#FFEE00;border-color:#FFFF00;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
a.active{background-color:#0088FF !important;}
a.active:hover{background-color:#00AAFF !important;}
.font1{font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;}
.font2{font-family:calibri;font-size:18px;text-decoration:underline;}
#menu1 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:20px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu1 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu1 li{display:inline-block;} 
#menu1 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
#menu2 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu2 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu2 li{display:inline-block;}
#menu2 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>De Geoclub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="menu1"><ul><li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li><li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul></div>
        <p><span class="font2">De Geoclub</span><br><br><span class="font1">Welkom op de website van de Geoclub. De Geoclub wordt gehouden in Reggesteyn Noetsele en is voor de leerlingen en oudleerlingen van Reggesteyn. Onze leider is Mr. Nauta, een docent aardrijkskunde op Reggesteyn Noetsele. Bij de Geoclub hebben we het over stenen, fossielen en mineralen. We houden soms bijeenkomsten en excursies. Om de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Hieronder kun je lezen over de bijeenkomsten en excursies. Verder kun je op onze website de agenda van de Geoclub bekijken en de foto's die we hebben genomen bekijken. Je kunt onder het tabblad 'contact' de adresgegevens van Mr. Nauta vinden. Veel plezier!</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Bijeenkomsten</span><br><br><span class="font1">Ongeveer eens per maand houden we een bijeenkomst in lokaal 209 in het gebouw van Reggesteyn Noetsele, meestal om 14.45. Soms bereidt Mr. Nauta iets voor en soms bereidt een leerling iets voor. We eten en drinken halverwege ook iets. Als je wilt weten wanneer de bijeenkomsten zijn, kun je kijken op de agenda. Voor de exacte tijden en mogelijke wijzigingen stuurt Mr. Nauta je een mailtje. Zorg er dus voor dat hij je emailadres heeft. Mr. Nauta's emailadres kun je vinden onder 'contact'. Je bent altijd welkom bij een bijeenkomst, het is niet verplicht. Verder zijn de bijeenkomsten gratis.</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Excursies</span><br><br><span class="font1">Met de Geoclub houden we ongeveer drie keer per jaar een excursie. Eens in de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Meestal bereiden we in de bijeenkomst voor een excursie de excursie voor, en in de bijeenkomst na de excursie laten we onze vondsten zien. Tijdens de excursies gaan we een aantal groeves langs om te zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen. Mr. Nauta en enkele ouders rijden. We vertrekken meestal rond 9 uur en we zijn rond 5 uur weer terug. Bij de grote excursies gaan we drie tot vier dagen weg. We gaan dan bijvoorbeeld naar Duitsland of Frankrijk. We kamperen daar of we huren een huisje. We zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen in de buurt van waar we overnachten. In de periode voor de grote excursie krijg je meer duidelijke informatie over de excursie.<br><br>Bij de gewone excursies is het handig om de volgende dingen mee te nemen: eten en drinken, een (moker) hamer, een puntige steenbeitel en een platte steenbeitel, iets om je vondsten in te bewaren en wat closetpapier om breekbare vondsten in te bewaren.<br><br>De gewone excursies kosten ongeveer 10 euro (voor benzine). De grote excursies kosten rond de honderd euro (voor benzine, eten en overnachting).</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Please run the snippet in full page mode for the best results.)

I'm trying to get the white-backgrounded body to the bottom of the page but it should go further if the text, due page resizement, exceeds the body. I've tried the CSS property height-min:100%; on the body, the html and both but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to get the body right?

Comment: What white background? it's shades of purple...

Comment: min-height cannot be inherited, you need to set at least height:100% to html in order to use min-height on body

Comment: It's transparent white. It seems purple because of the background. In the real version the background is an image but I couldn't get that in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min-height` cannot be inherited, you need to set at least `height:100%` to `html` in order to use `min-height` on `body`

```css
html {height:100%;}
html, body {cursor:url(files/cursor.cur),progress;min-height:100%;}
html{background-color:#6666FF;;background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center;background-size:cover;}
body{width:80%;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}
p{margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px;text-align: center;}
iframe{overflow:hidden;height:80%;width:100%;}
img{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:calibri;border-style:outset;border-color:#FFFF00;border-width:5px;}
td{font-size:16px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#FFFF00;background-color:#FFFFFF}
th{font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#FFEE00;border-color:#FFFF00;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;}
a.active{background-color:#0088FF !important;}
a.active:hover{background-color:#00AAFF !important;}
.font1{font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;}
.font2{font-family:calibri;font-size:18px;text-decoration:underline;}
#menu1 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:20px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu1 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu1 li{display:inline-block;} 
#menu1 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
#menu2 a{display:block;background-color:#0066FF;text-decoration:none;font-family:calibri;font-size:16px;color:#FFFFFF;padding:10px 10px;} 
#menu2 a:hover{background-color:#00AAFF;} 
#menu2 li{display:inline-block;}
#menu2 ul{list-style:none;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;padding:0px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>De Geoclub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="menu1"><ul><li><a href="index.html">Welkom</a></li><li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li><li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul></div>
        <p><span class="font2">De Geoclub</span><br><br><span class="font1">Welkom op de website van de Geoclub. De Geoclub wordt gehouden in Reggesteyn Noetsele en is voor de leerlingen en oudleerlingen van Reggesteyn. Onze leider is Mr. Nauta, een docent aardrijkskunde op Reggesteyn Noetsele. Bij de Geoclub hebben we het over stenen, fossielen en mineralen. We houden soms bijeenkomsten en excursies. Om de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Hieronder kun je lezen over de bijeenkomsten en excursies. Verder kun je op onze website de agenda van de Geoclub bekijken en de foto's die we hebben genomen bekijken. Je kunt onder het tabblad 'contact' de adresgegevens van Mr. Nauta vinden. Veel plezier!</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Bijeenkomsten</span><br><br><span class="font1">Ongeveer eens per maand houden we een bijeenkomst in lokaal 209 in het gebouw van Reggesteyn Noetsele, meestal om 14.45. Soms bereidt Mr. Nauta iets voor en soms bereidt een leerling iets voor. We eten en drinken halverwege ook iets. Als je wilt weten wanneer de bijeenkomsten zijn, kun je kijken op de agenda. Voor de exacte tijden en mogelijke wijzigingen stuurt Mr. Nauta je een mailtje. Zorg er dus voor dat hij je emailadres heeft. Mr. Nauta's emailadres kun je vinden onder 'contact'. Je bent altijd welkom bij een bijeenkomst, het is niet verplicht. Verder zijn de bijeenkomsten gratis.</span></p>
        <p><span class="font2">De Excursies</span><br><br><span class="font1">Met de Geoclub houden we ongeveer drie keer per jaar een excursie. Eens in de twee jaar houden we een grote, meerdaagse excursie. Meestal bereiden we in de bijeenkomst voor een excursie de excursie voor, en in de bijeenkomst na de excursie laten we onze vondsten zien. Tijdens de excursies gaan we een aantal groeves langs om te zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen. Mr. Nauta en enkele ouders rijden. We vertrekken meestal rond 9 uur en we zijn rond 5 uur weer terug. Bij de grote excursies gaan we drie tot vier dagen weg. We gaan dan bijvoorbeeld naar Duitsland of Frankrijk. We kamperen daar of we huren een huisje. We zoeken naar stenen, fossielen en mineralen in de buurt van waar we overnachten. In de periode voor de grote excursie krijg je meer duidelijke informatie over de excursie.<br><br>Bij de gewone excursies is het handig om de volgende dingen mee te nemen: eten en drinken, een (moker) hamer, een puntige steenbeitel en een platte steenbeitel, iets om je vondsten in te bewaren en wat closetpapier om breekbare vondsten in te bewaren.<br><br>De gewone excursies kosten ongeveer 10 euro (voor benzine). De grote excursies kosten rond de honderd euro (voor benzine, eten en overnachting).</span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for the answer for days!